# How to implement DI service configurator in Automation Engine service registration

Tags: dependency-injection, marketing-automation

I am seeking to inject a service with dependencies into a `Marketing Automation Activity Type` that will be instantiated by the `Marketing Automation Engine`.

I have successfully injected a basic service as per the [docs](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/inject-your-own-activity-type-service.html), but the service I want to use has an existing `IServicesConfigurator` implementation:

```
public class ServiceBusConfigurator : IServicesConfigurator 
    {
        public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            serviceCollection.AddSingleton(typeof(IServiceBusQueueOptions<>), typeof(ServiceBusQueueOptions<>));
            serviceCollection.AddSingleton(typeof(IServiceBusTopicOptions<>), typeof(ServiceBusTopicOptions<>));
            serviceCollection.AddSingleton(typeof(IServiceBusQueue<>), typeof(ServiceBusQueue<>));
            serviceCollection.AddTransient(typeof(IServiceBusTopic<>), typeof(ServiceBusTopic<>));

            serviceCollection.AddTransient(typeof(IPublishJourneyStatusService), typeof(PublishJourneyStatusService));
        }
    }
```

The XML config for wiring up the dependency differs from the usual Sitecore pattern (see below) and I am unsure as to how to do this in the `Automation Engine` configuration.

```
<Settings>
<Sitecore>
    <XConnect>
    <MarketingAutomation>
        <Engine>
        <Services>
            <Foo.Foundation.PublishService>
                <Type>Foo.Foundation.MarketingAutomation.Services.PublishService, Foo.Foundation.MarketingAutomation</Type>
                <As>Foo.Foundation.MarketingAutomation.Services.IPublishService, Foo.Foundation.MarketingAutomation</As>
                <LifeTime>Singleton</LifeTime>
            </Foo.Foundation.PublishService>
        </Services>
        </Engine>
    </MarketingAutomation>
    </XConnect>
</Sitecore>
</Settings>
```

Is there a way to achieve this in either the engine XML configuration or in the Activity Type or even another injected service ?

Sitecore version is 9.1 initial release.

Comment: In theory, I should have been able to just wire up the other dependencies but that didn't work either. After a fair bit of experimentation, I think that the problem is with instantiating the generic types such as IServiceBusTopic<>, since other services work fine.

Comment: I've not had any problems with the xml config you listed before, but then I've not tried registering Generics. It's slightly different usecase, but in e.g. Autofac they allow config via xml (https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/xml.html) and suggest `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(typeof(IRepository<string>).AssemblyQualifiedName);` to get the val you need in config file.